# Using generics in Java, can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like so

```
public interface Handler<T> {

    /**
     * @param request
     * @return
     * @throws ServiceErrorResponse
     */

    public Credit handle(T request) throws ServiceErrorResponse;

    public Data handle() throws ServiceErrorResponse;
}
```

And it is implemented by this

```
public class DataHandlerImpl implements Handler {

    public Credit handle(T request) {
        return new Policy();
    }

    public Data handle() {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

However, this throws an error because it cannot resolve the symbol T. I have tried multiple things like doing this as the signature but it also doesn't work

```
public class DataHandlerImpl implements Handler<T> {
```

I have also tried

```
public class DataHandlerImpl implements Handler {

    public Policy handle(String request) {
        return new Policy();
    }

    public Data handle() {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

which doesn't work because I must implement `handle(T)`

but seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of generics. Can someone please explain?

I want this "handle" method to be able to accept strings or integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really have the same method take both strings and ints, assuming that the implantation of the method will be different to handle different types.  For generics, when you write your implementing class you need to specify which argument it will take.  Your compiler should actually be giving you a warning for having implements without a type.

```
public class DataHandlerStringImpl implements Handler<String> 
public class DataHandlerIntegermpl implements Handler<Integer>
```

The non-generics way to do this would be overloaded methods, which are simpler but less extensible/powerful.  The compiler will know which implemention to use based on the type passed in.

```
public Credit handle(String request) 
public Credit handle(int request)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what type you want `handle(...)` to take and apply that as the `Handler<T>` type. For `String` example:

```java
    public static class DataHandlerImpl implements Handler<String> {
        @Override
        public Credit handle(String request) {
            return new CreditPolicy();
        }

        @Override
        public Data handle() {
            return new CreditPoliciesData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see, so that means I cannot pass either a String or Int here?

Comment: You have a few options: 1) Use the common type of `Integer` and `String`;  this is `Object`, so no need for generics. 2) Create a type that holds an `int` and `String`. 3) Have `Handler` use 2 generic types `<T, U>` and two methods `handleT(T t)` and `handleU(U u)`

Comment: @sf8193 Food for thought: If the method could take either strings or ints, what would an implementation of the method look like? What methods could you use on the args, given that you don't know their type? You can't multiply it by 5 (as if it's an int) cause it might be a String; you can't get its length (as if it's a String), cause it might be an int. Java's type system doesn't let you say "type A or B", so the arg would have to be Object -- which could be anything, not just String or int. What you're asking for is reasonable, but it doesn't fit in Java's type system. :)